# TortoiseGit Regex filter

Tags: regex, git, github, tortoisegit

I have a GIT repo and many commits from a guy which did tons of initial commits which we did when moving on GIT from SVN.

Now I want to exclude the guys commit from the history for which i want to make a statistic.

I tried filters like

```
-username, (?!^username$)
```

with regex turned on and so on... but none of them want to work. How can I filter out a user from my commit log?

The one which you get when you right click the repo folder and go on TortoiseGit and click on Show Log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your RegEx to: `^(?!^username$)`. This will result in a positive match, but if you want to retrieve the actual username matching this condition, change the RegEx to: `^(?!^username$).+`.

Comment: ^(?!^Remove$)[\w0-9]+ didnt work to. I tried to filter for all criteria, no reaction.

Comment: Hmm, must be an issue with git rather than the RegEx. I am unfortunately at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseGit 1.8.7.1 will support negative log filter

It starts with an exclamation mark. Please uncheck regular expression, as it is not regex.

You may use `Toggle checked filters` to help uncheck all filters other than `Authors`.

Expression `!You` means to exclude `You`

[image: Negative Filter]

Comment: Let's try TortoiseGit 1.8.7.1 preview